# Give status update from a Spring controller method before actually returning

Tags: spring, controller

I have three endpoints in a web application, `/overview`, `/insert`, and `/update`. At `/insert` the user can specify some data and submit to `/update` where the data is processed. In `/overview` a user can see the status.

The `/update` itself consists of two steps: verification and actually doing the update. When the verification fails the user is redirected again to `/insert` to change the data. When the verification is successful, the user is redirected to `/overview` to see the updated data. The code is like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public ModelAndView processData(ModelMap model, @RequestParam(value = "data", required = true) String data) {

    // Do some verification, this needs some time
    boolean verificationFailed = verify(data);

    // In case of failed verification, return to insert page
    if (verificationFailed) {
        return new ModelAndView("insert", model);
    }

    // TODO: send some udpate to the web page

    // Perform some action
    doSomething(data);

    // Redirect to overview page to see the effects
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/overview", model);
}
```

The process needs some time for verification and the actual processing (a few seconds, probably up to half a minute each). I would like to give the user an update after successful verification, such that the website can be updated with a link to `/overview` that the user can click if she suspects a timeout.

The two steps verification/processing should be launched by only one click by the user, it is also assumed that the verification is typically successful.

Comment: I suspect a good solution would be to have the UI query the status in an ajax call. Think about it, perhaps you may reword the question (and/or add tags). You could mention your UI technologies in question+tags.

Comment: You mean, the UI should query the status every few seconds? I did not think the UI technologies are that important. I use Freemarker and jQuery in an HTML5 webpage.

Comment: Consider using [DeferredResult](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.html). Something similar with [this](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/16/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-chat-sample/) can be employed in your case.

Comment: I'll rephrase: I didn't say "query every few seconds", I only mentioned Ajax could be used and mentioning your UI technologies may help. The ajax call very well be a single call (with some code executed on request sent + other code on request completed). @Bond-JavaBond's suggestion is pretty good too! This site describes both ways: http://java.ulitzer.com/node/3110026/mobile